# Magento 1.9 - Redirect to custom URL with hash

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm currently working on a comment system on my product view. The problem I'm trying to solve is redirecting the user back to the comments section in the product view after the user logs in.

I read I can include a `/referer/` in the URL of the log in page (for example, `/customer/account/login/referer/path/to/product#comments`) and that would redirect me back to the URL path I want. I tried this and it doesn't work.

Anyone know how I can go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you want to redirect all logins to this comment page or only the user tried to comment and login?

Comment: @Mujahidh hi, only the user tried to comment and login.

Comment: yes try the answer.hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

Hi use `setBeforeAuthUrl` method in your code.
use below code in the product comment section when requesting the customer login.

```
if(!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')
        ->setBeforeAuthUrl(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl()); 
echo '<p>Please <a href="'.Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login').'">Login</a> to view the page.</p>';
}
```